# VB.NET Como simular clicks do mouse (Real)

Tags: vb.net

Olá, eu sei que há muitas perguntas desse tipo, mas o que eu quero saber não é como simular, mas sim como REALMENTE fazer um programa clicar de verdade. Eu já sei como simular os clicks perfeitamente, mas eu fiz um teste em um website que detecta "autoclickers" , e ele mostra que estou clicando, porém que meu botão do mouse não está sendo pressionado. Há algum jeito de fazer com que ao mesmo tempo que simule os clicks, mostre que o botão do mouse está sendo pressionado? Aguardo resposta, e agradeço desde já.

Comment: O ideal é que sua pergunta seja específica e trate do problema técnico, esta muito amplo e difícil de ajudar. Mas veja bem, eu acredito que para isso você precise entender sobre `crawlers` e sobre a `renderização`.
Pelo que ja vi, o maior desafio nessa situação, é que geralmente as páginas carregas dessa forma não executam o JavaScript posterior ao carregamento, o que possibilita facilmente do provedor do recurso saber que não é um tráfego real.

Comment: Um bom exemplo disso é o IPTS, que é um Bot Chines que faz o que você quer com uma certa perfeição. Mas se sua intenção for fazer algo no estilo Adsense, precisa de muito mais do que apenas a simulação do click.